# Region monitoring stops after iPhone restart

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I am monitoring `CLBeaconRegion` and its working fine. Even the terminated app (Swiped and killed by user) is getting launched  with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` at enter and exit region delegate calls. But one borderline case remains un resolved, when i restart my iPhone and then enter the beacon region i receive no call in `didEnterRegion` nor the app is launched.Kindly suggest is it normal behavior or there is some thing amiss from my end

Comment: Hi as it turns out it was due to beta version of my iPhone the same implementation is working as intended in stable OS